# BGP - Advertise VRF routes

Tags: routing, bgp, vrf

I have a router with a Global Routing Table (GRT), and a VRF. My end goal is to advertise to my eBGP neighbor my VRF routes.

I have actually successfully done it by using address-families (ipv4, vpnv4), creating a Vlan interface in that VRF (vrf forwarding) and using this IP for the peering. That means I am using 2 IPs to peer with my neighbor, one that advertises the GRT routes (my physical interface), and the Vlan interface advertises the VRF routes. So basically, I have 2 neighbor statements.

But I'm wondering if it is possible to advertise my VRF routes using my physical interface (which is not part of that VRF) only. Would I have to first leak my VRF routes into the GRT to do this ?

Comment: What router model and firmware version are you using?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Would I have to first leak my VRF routes into the GRT to do this?

Yes, you need to leak the routes.

But this is not enough.  You also have to leak (at least some of) your GRT routes into the VRF for the return traffic.  Also, you need to provide a data path for the actual traffic.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about the GRT into the VRF. But what did you mean with "data path for the actual traffic" ?